# Visualizing The Project Tango Point Cloud

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I was working on something and I was wondering why the Tango developers, for Unity3D, chose to visualize the point cloud by manipulating the vertices of a mesh instead of using the built-in particle system? From my experience it seems a lot more work to get points working in a shader; I had trouble resizing points in the shader for whatever reason even though I pretty much copied and pasted Tango's Point Cloud Shader plus a bunch of other problems.

Comment: You should be able to resize the points by using gl_pointSize in shaders. But there's really no particular reason to use mesh vs. particle system in this case.

Comment: How on Earth did you get Tango working inside Unity3D without crashing every 30 seconds?

Comment: @PeterMorris I followed the instructions on the Tango site. https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/

Answer (score 0):

You can do one billion points at 90fps on Unity3D if you use it the right way. You cannot resize the points on Unity anymore. Unity3D just blew it from us - (it is still working on DirectX 9). forget about gl_pointSize - not working; you have to do Geometry Shader for sized points.